# Formating a calendar table to a datetime dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a calendar data in the following format:

```
        df = pd.read_csv('2021.txt', sep="  ")
        df.head()
```

[image]

I'd like to have it as:

```
   Date       y
 2021-01-01 17:26
 2021-01-02 17:27
 2021-01-03 17:28
 2021-01-04 17:28
      ...
 2021-12-31 17:25
```

I've searched and found no similar questions. I'm trying to provide a minimal example but don't know where to start. I know I have to use pandas.to_datetime function but I don't even know how to apply it in this case because everything is separated.

Comment: The minimal example can be the first two rows of your `2021.txt` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `errros='coerce'` for convert wrong datetimes like `2021-02-30` to missing values and then remove this rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('Day', var_name='Date', value_name='y')
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2021'  + df1['Date'] + df1.pop('Day').astype(str), 
                             format='%Y%b%d', errors='coerce')
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['Date'])
print (df1)  
         Date      y
0  2021-01-01  17:28
1  2021-01-02  17:27
2  2021-01-03  17:28
3  2021-01-04  17:28
4  2021-01-05  17:29
..        ...    ...
67 2021-12-02  17:15
68 2021-12-03  17:15
69 2021-12-04  17:15
70 2021-12-05  17:15
71 2021-12-06  17:15

[72 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error "melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variable_name'

Comment: @Numbermind - Sorry, I change it already.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept your answer as soon as it works. The first line of your code works. But the seconds gives me the error "ValueError: day is out of range for month"

Comment: @Numbermind - Understand, so answer was edited.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The second line of your script keeps giving errors. Now with 'coere' gives the following error: "AssertionError:"

Comment: @Numbermind - oops, my typo, missing `c` - `errors='coerce'`