# Convert tabular calendar date to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my dataframe is like these:

[image]

The columns are days (column 0), months(1-12) and year

i want to convert dataframe to datetime

```
1998-01-01 NaN
1998-01-02 2099.54
1998-01-03 NaN
1998-01-04 NaN
1998-01-05 2117.38
...
```

How Can I do this in python?

Comment: column ` 0` is data and col `Ano` is year . which one is the `month` ?

Comment: columns 1 to 12 are the months. column 0 is the day, column Ano is the year

Comment: Something like this should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65577847/formating-a-calendar-table-to-a-datetime-dataframe